# ImportError: cannot import name 'deepmac_meta_arch' from 'object_detection.meta_architectures'

Tags: python, tensorflow

trying to work with tensorflow object detection. Running the verification code:

```
VERIFICATION_SCRIPT = os.path.join(paths['APIMODEL_PATH'], 'research', 'object_detection', 'builders', 'model_builder_tf2_test.py')
```

## Verify Installation

!python {VERIFICATION_SCRIPT}

to check the installation of all necessary modules, but receiving an error:

```
  I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection.meta_architectures import deepmac_meta_arch
ImportError: cannot import name 'deepmac_meta_arch' from 'object_detection.meta_architectures' (F:\Python\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\meta_architectures\__init__.py)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Facing the same issue here!

Comment: @Victor Malichenko, Is your issue resolved now? Else, please can you try to use `Tensorflow 2.x` version incase you are using `Tensorflow 1.x`.  For more details, please refer [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/55591#issuecomment-1098167469). Thanks!